# Non existence of a preferred Horizontal subspace.

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

If I choose a principal bundle, let us say $G\rightarrow P \rightarrow B$, with $G=U(1)$, $P=T^2$ (2-torus) and $B=S^1$. Can I choose follow the identity element for every $x$ of the base space? Doesn't this imply that there is a preferred Horizontal subspace (the one tangent to every point of the curves I have described), and thus a canonical connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to be precise but informal.

Let $\pi:P\to B$ be the trivial principal $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$ and let $x\in B$ be any point. Then:

1. There is no preferred point of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(x)$.
2. Given a point $y\in \pi^{-1}(x)$, there is no preferred point of nearby fibers; if $U\ni x$ is a neighborhood of $x\in B$, there is no preferred section $s$ of $\pi$ over $U$ such that $s(x)=y$.

Why? As a first approximation to the answer, just imagine a perfect unit circle $C$ in some strange position in space. It is diffeomorphic, even isometric, to our "standard" copy of $S^1 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ in many different ways (this "standard" $S^1$ has a "standard" group structure, fixed once and for all, in which the identity is $(1,0)$. We could have chosen the identity differently, but we didn't.) We know what it means to rotate the circle $C$, so there is an $S^1$-action on it. But we don't have a preferred "identity point" on it! If you choose some $p\in C$ and I choose some different $q\in C$, neither of us has a better choice. There is an isometry $C\to S^1$ taking $p$ to $(1,0)$ but there is also an isometry taking $q$ to $(1,0)$.

The above paragraph is all you need to understand point (1) above: the fiber over a point is just something that looks like a circle and has a circle action, so without additional information it has no preferred point. If $\pi:P\to B$ is given in some abstract manner, you can't "choose" a point in the fiber that *correponds to* your favorite point on some standard copy of $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, because there is no preferred *correspondence*.

Even if $\pi:P\to B$ is given concretely by an atlas of charts you may not be able to choose a distinguished point in each fiber. The atlas may identify the fibers with the circle $C$ from above, for instance.

Point (2) is kind of similar.

That $\pi$ is trivial means the following: let $$p: S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$$ $$p(a,b)=a.$$ This is a trivial principal $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$. Then since $\pi$ is trivial also, there is an isomorphism of principal bundles. This is a diffeomorphism $f:P\to S^1 \times S^1$ such that $$p\circ f = \pi$$ and which is equivariant with respect to the $S^1$-action, meaning $$f(y.g) = f(y).g$$ for all $y\in P$ and all $g\in S^1$.

However, there are many many different isomorphisms of this kind. Indeed, let $h:S^1 \to S^1$ be any smooth function (I don't care about injectivity or *any* other condition). Then the function
$$P \to S^1 \times S^1$$
$$y \mapsto f(y.h(\pi(y)))$$
is also an isomorphism of principal bundles from $P$ to the trivial bundle. Any two isomorphisms from $P$ to the trivial bundle are related by such an $h$. Who is to say which $h$ gives the best isomorphism?

If $h_1(t) = 1$ and $h_2(t)=t$ are two functions $S^1 \to S^1$, and $f$ is some isomorphism from $P$ to the trivial bundle, we get two different isomorphisms in this way, and we can't deformed one into the other continuously. Of course the isomorphism constructed using $f$ and $h_1$ is $f$ itself, but that doesn't make it better than the other.

Comment: This is mixing up vertical and horizontal. Given a choice of a point $p$ on $C$, you can (using the group action, essentially as you suggest) identify it with the identity element of $S^1$, and then label all other elements of $C$ by elements of $S^1$ using the map $S^1 \to C$ given by $t \mapsto p.t$. This is good. But now let's take a point $x'$ near $x$ in the base space. How should we pick a point $p'$ above $x'$ which is "near" $p$? There is no preferred choice (this is what the second half of my answer explains).

Comment: With finite groups you will not see this kind of phenomenon. If the fiber is a finite group then the principal bundle is a covering space, and there are unique liftings of paths from $B$ to $P$.

Comment: Here is a geometric picture: take a cylinder, place it horizontally on your desk (so it is free to roll, but let us suppose that it doesn't). Think of it  as an $S^1$-principal bundle over the interval $[0,1]$. You can pick a point $p$ in the fiber over some point $x$ of $[0,1]$, and say that your section is a horizontal segment of the cylinder passing through this point. But now you walk away for a while, and I come to your desk and twist the cylinder a little bit. The notion of a horizontal "straight segment" changes. However, the fiber over each point remains the same.

Comment: The total space doesn't know anything about vertical or horizontal, but the projection to the base space knows what "vertical" means.

Comment: (Maybe the comment on the cylinder will be clearer if I emphasize that I do not *turn* the cylinder, I *twist* it. So what was once a straight horizontal segment now twists a little around the cylinder.)

Comment: You could put it that way, but I think it's more helpful to look at it this way: You are looking at a single smooth cylinder $P\to [0,1]$ with projection to the interval. The fibers are circles with $S^1$-action. But it has no preferred geometry, so a path in $[0,1]$ has no preferred corresponding "horizontal" path  in $P$ lying over it, even if we chose one point over a point of the path in $[0,1]$. You can't say "this path is straight," or that "this path twists around the cylinder," etc. You can only say: "this path in $P$ lies over that path in $[0,1]$." Hence: no preferred section.

Comment: @CouplingConstant I'm not sure what you're asking. The fibers are not disconnected (in the one sense I can think of). The manifold is not the space of all smooth functions in any sense I can think of, either. I would suggest taking a short break and rereading the first comments in this comment thread, then possibly opening a new question?

Comment: Sure thanks a lot